# Deploying a Node TCP Server onto AWS or Heroku

Tags: node.js, deployment, tcp, chat

So basically, I am trying to deploy my chat server app onto Heroku and then I enabled web sockets via the command 'heroku labs:enable websockets'

I have a feeling that my Procfile is wrong... I think that having it do a web process is wrong.

`web: node app.js`

Continuing along, I need to **host my ChatServer** and be able to connect to it via **telnet**. I have been trying to do so for the past 2 hours. Help plssss!

```
var net = require('net')
var Parser = require('./Parser')
var Writer = require('./Writer')
var Broadcaster = require('./Broadcaster')
var Room = require('./Room')
var SocketUsername = require('./SocketUsername')
var Command = require('./Command')
var RoomHelper = require('./RoomHelper')

var server = net.Server()

server.listen(1337)

var sockets = []
var rooms = []

var DEFAULTROOM = "home"

rooms.push(new Room(DEFAULTROOM))

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.room = DEFAULTROOM
  sockets.push(socket)

  Writer.greet(socket)
  Writer.askName(socket)

  socket.on('data', respondToUserInput)
  socket.on('end', removeSocket)
})

function removeSocket() {
  var i = sockets.indexOf(this)
  sockets.splice(i, 1)
}

function respondToUserInput(data) {
  var currentSocket = this
  var userInput = data.toString().trim()
  if (currentSocket.username) {
    var parsedInput = Parser.analyzeInput(userInput)
    if (Command.isValid(parsedInput["command"])) {
      Command.execute(parsedInput, currentSocket, rooms, sockets)
    }
    if (parsedInput["dialog"]) {
      Broadcaster.postDialog(currentSocket, userInput, sockets)
    }
  } else {
    if (SocketUsername.isAvailable(userInput, sockets) && SocketUsername.isValid(userInput)) {
      SocketUsername.assign.call(currentSocket, userInput)
      Writer.welcomeUser(currentSocket, currentSocket.username)
      Broadcaster.announceEnteredRoom(currentSocket, sockets)
    } else {
      Writer.notifyNameInvalid(currentSocket)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can activate web sockets on Heroku now: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta

Comment: I launched it to heroku and enabled websockets. However, it still wont connect... Is my procfile perhaps wrong?? web: node app.js